# Переход к новому базису с поворотом одной из осей

Tags: математика

Длины базисных векторов e1 и е2 общей декартовой системы координат на плоскости равны соответственно 4 и 2, а угол между базисными векторами равен 120°. Относительно этой системы координат заданы вершины треугольника А(-2,2), В(-2,-1), С(-1,0). Найти длины сторон и углы треугольника.

Есть ответ
|АВ| = 6, |АС| = 4√3, |ВС| = 2√3, A = 30°, B = 90°, C = 60°.
Как к нему прийти?

Comment: Это лучше спрашивать на сайте [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Что мешает нарисовать на листочке и посчитать геометрически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте по простому:

Положим в декартовой системе `e1=(4,0)`, тогда второй вектор `e2=(-1,√3)`

Вектор AB в кривой системе имеет коэффициенты `(-2+2,-1-2)=(0,3)`

Значит, в декартовой его компоненты будут

```
AB.x = 0*e1.x + 3*e2.x = -3
AB.y = 0*e1.y + 3*e2.y = -3*√3
```

его длина

```
|AB| = √((-3)²+(-3*√3)²) = √(9+27) = 6
```

Вектор AC в кривой системе имеет коэффициенты `(-1+2,0-2)=(1,-2)`

Его компоненты в декартовой

```
AС.x = 1*e1.x - 2*e2.x = 4 - (2*-1) = 6
AС.y = 1*e1.y - 2*e2.y = - 2*√3
```

его длина

```
|AС| = √(6²+(-2*√3)²) = √(36+12) = √(48) = 4√3
```

Дальше понятно?

Answer (score 1):

После предложения @MBo *давайте по-простому*, просто невозможно удержаться и не предложить **по-плохому** :)

Итак, как уже установил @MBo, *в декартовой системе e1=(4,0), тогда второй вектор e2=(-1,√3)*

Да начнётся *плохое*!

Для системы координат `[e1, e2]` метрический тензор будет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Напомню, что скалярное прозведение векторо с координатами [image: введите сюда описание изображения] выражается через метрический тензор как [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решается ваша задача через скалярное произведение векторов?

0. Вектор, соответствующий третьей стороне треугольника, равен [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
1. Длина вектора [image: введите сюда описание изображения] есть квадратный корень из скалярного произведения вектора на сам себя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Косинус угла между векторами [image: введите сюда описание изображения] по теореме о скалярном произведении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Напомню...` - это хорошо звучит ;)

Comment: @MBo в свою защиту могу сказать, что я хотя бы использовал знак суммирования и не ссылался на *правило суммирования Эйнштейна* ;) И вообще, метрический тензор и скалярное произведение точно изучают в разделе "Билинейные формы" (насколько помню), поэтому за пределы линейки (ака линейная алгебра) для первого курса я не вышел.